# Ruby search a string for matching character pairs

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match character pairs in a string.  Let's say the string is:
"zttabcgqztwdegqf".  Both "zt" and "gq" are matching pairs of characters in the string.

The following code finds the "zt" matching pair, but not the "gq" pair:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
string = "zttabcgqztwdegqf"
puts string.scan(/.{1,2}/).detect{ |c| string.count(c) > 1 }
```

The code provides matching pairs where the indices of the pairs are 0&1,2&3,4&5... but not 1&2,3&4,5&6, etc:

```
zt
ta
bc
gq
zt
wd
eg
qf
```

I'm not sure regex in Ruby is the best way to go.  But I want to use Ruby for the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question I've just answered. :-).  The title refers to a "matching character pair". Could you please define that (with an edit)? Also, is your desired output simply the array `["zt", "ta", "bc", "gq", "zt", "wd", "eg", "qf"]` (which is each pair of adjacent strings joined)?

Comment: Suppose the string were "ttabcttttdefttbcbcbc". What would be your desired output?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: if i understand correctly he wants to found every couple of chars (also the overlapping ones) that is repeated inside the string, his problem is related with the regex engine consuming chars two per times, so the odd couples is not extracted.

Comment: @Gsus, I expect so, but I want the OP to confirm.

Comment: Thanks to both Gsus and Cary.  Yes I am looking for two characters repeated, as per the examples I provided.  Thank you Gsus for the awesome regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your search with a single regex:

```
puts string.scan(/(?=(.{2}).*\1)/)
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF4eO4/2)</kbd>

**Output**

> zt
>   gq

**Regex Breakout**

```
(?=       # Start a lookahead
   (.{2}) # Search any couple of char and group it in \1
   .*\1   # Search ahead in the string for another \1 to validate
)         # Close lookahead
```

**Note**

Putting all the checks inside lookahead assure the regex engine does not consume the couple when validates it. 
So it also works with overlapping couples like in the string `abcabc`: the output will correctly be `ab`,`bc`.

**Oddity**

If the regex engine does not consume the chars how it can reach the end of the string?

Internally after the check *Onigmo* (the ruby regex engine) makes one step further automatically. Most regex flavours behaves in this way but e.g. the javascript engine needs the programmer to increment the last match index manually.

Comment: The question is horrible. I read your answer repeatedly, and understood the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: i've updated the answer to remove the flaw, thanks for the review

Comment: Very nice, better than what I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "ztcabcgqzttwtcdegqf"

r = /
    (.) # match any character in capture group 1
    (?= # begin a positive lookahead 
    (.) # match any character in capture group 2
    .+  # match >= 1 characters
    \1  # match capture group 1
    \2  # match capture group 2
    )   # close positive lookahead
    /x   # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan(r).map(&:join)
  #=> ["zt", "tc", "gq"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this without using regex:

```
string = "zttabcgqztwdegqf"
p string.split('').each_cons(2).map(&:join).select {|i| string.scan(i).size > 1 }.uniq
#=> ["zt", "gq"]
```